# valarray with arithmetic operations return type

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, valarray

When I write a simple arithmetic expression with `valarray` and assign the result to `auto` I get a segfault when I try to access the result on gcc.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
using std::ostream; using std::valarray;
ostream& operator<<(ostream&os, const valarray<double>&vs) {
    os << "[";
    for(auto&v : vs) os << v << " ";
    return os << "]";
}
int main() {
    valarray<double> a{ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 };
    std::cout << "a: " << a << "\n";
    valarray<double> b{ 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0 };
    std::cout << "b: " << b << "\n";
    valarray<double> c{ 2.0, 1.5, 0.5, 0.25 };
    std::cout << "c: " << c << "\n";
    valarray<double> x = ( a + b ) / 2;
    std::cout << "x: " << x << "\n";
    // this still works:
    auto y = ( a + b ) / 2;
    // The following will result in a segfault:
    std::cout << "y:" << y << "\n";
}
```

The [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/valarray/operators/) says that the implementation may choose that the return type of the arithmetic operation overloads may not be a `valarray`-value but something that "behaves like it":

> The operators returning a valarray by value are allowed to return an object of a different type instead. Such a type is required to be implicitly convertible to valarray and be supported as argument for all functions taking valarray& arguments. This allows copy-on-write implementations.

Well, my `operator<<` should call for that "implicit conversion", shouldnt it?

So why do I get a segfault?

```
$ ./valarray01.cpp.x
a: [1 2 3 4 ]
b: [2 4 6 8 ]
c: [2 1.5 0.5 0.25 ]
x: [1.5 3 4.5 6 ]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

> gcc version 6.2.0 20160901 (Ubuntu 6.2.0-3ubuntu11~14.04)

I got sceptical when I tried *clang* (on linux, so probably gcc's stdlib) and... it works:

> clang version 3.9.1-svn288847-1~exp1 (branches/release_39)

```
$ ./valarray01.cpp.x
a: [1 2 3 4 ]
b: [2 4 6 8 ]
c: [2 1.5 0.5 0.25 ]
x: [1.5 3 4.5 6 ]
y:[1.5 3 4.5 6 ]
```

Well, before I file a gcc-bug... am I doing something wrong? Is my `auto` evil? Or is it really gcc?

Comment: I tried to print the elements individually and that works, might be another data point for debugging

Comment: Works for me with gcc 6.3, valgrind doesn't complain either.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. g++-5.4.1 works for me too. Hrm... bad.

Comment: Also works with clang 3.9 and libc++.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Got the segfault in valgrind, too. Seems to be an "invalid read of size 8". From the look of the stacktrace I suspect there is some expression-templating in there in valarray? whow! I wasnt suspecting that, but maybe I am wrong. `std::_Expr<std::_BinClos<std::__divides, std::_Expr, std::_Constant, std::_BinClos<std::__plus, std::_ValArray, ...` etc. Ok, maybe just brittle/difficult code that has been fixed in later gcc's.

Comment: Works in `msvc 14` but fails [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40391eafff23ee60). Might be related to [this problem](http://gcc-bugs.gcc.gnu.narkive.com/K7lFwmVv/bug-libstdc-57997-new-segmentation-fault-after-returning-valarray-expression-from-an-auto-function). When you remove `/ 2` it doesn't crash.

Comment: @mpiatek Yes indeed, looks very similar. Wait, I can check with MSVC, too. Hang on... Oops, no get an error there too. I use *rextester.com/rundotnet/api* for MSVC, though. No chance for deep digging.

Comment: valarray uses expression templates. **Never** use `auto` anywhere near expression templates.

Comment: Doesn't crash if built with gcc 7.2.0

Comment: Works as well in gcc 7.3.0

Comment: To the people saying it works with GCC 7, try checking it with `-fsanitize=address` or with optimization enabled. See https://gcc.gnu.org/PR83860 for a related bug report.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because GCC's `valarray` implementation uses [Expression Templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates) to avoid temporary objects being created for intermediate results of arithmetic expressions. Expression templates and `auto` do not mix well.

What happens is that `( a + b )` does not perform the multiplication immediately, instead it creates a "closure" object which has references to `a` and `b`. The actual multiplication will be delayed until the closure is used in a context that requires the result. Next, the rest of the expression `( a + b ) / 2` creates a second closure object which holds a reference to the first closure object, and a reference to the value `2`. That second closure object is then used to initialize a variable with the type deduced by `auto`:

```
auto y = ( a + b ) / 2;
```

So `y` is a closure object that has a reference to the first closure, and to an `int` with value `2`. However, the first closure and the `int` value were both temporaries, which go out of scope at the end of the statement. This means that `y` has two dangling references, to a temporary closure and to a temporary `int`. When you try to use `y` in the `cout` statement it gets converted to a `valarray<double>` which tries to evaluate the results of the multiplication and the division. That evaluation follows the dangling references and tries to access temporary objects that no longer exist. That means undefined behaviour.

I'm working on a patch for GCC that will help make code like this less error-prone (for [Bug 83860](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83860)), although it will still be fragile to combine `auto` with expression templates.

The code works fine if you don't use `auto` i.e.

```
std::valarray<double> y = (a+b)/2;
```

Here the expression templates get evaluated before the temporaries go out of scope, and so there are no dangling references.

This particular example can be made to "work" by compiling with `-fstack-reuse=none` which disables the optimizations that reuse the stack space used by the temporary objects. This means the dangling references can still be used to access the temporaries after their lifetime ends. This is just a band-aid, not a real solution. The real solution is to not mix expression templates and `auto`.